What happens when you insert an inductor between Vcc and a MOSFET's drain?
Inserting an inductor in between Vcc and a MOSFET's drains can cause some very large voltage spikes, depending on the exact inductor value:

I'm having trouble analyzing it properly, though.  For some L values, the spikes are positive; for others negative; and the magnitude varies greatly, increasing up to a certain point, then going to 0.  How can I predict the voltage spikes?
Here's a better circuit:

How can I predict the Vout based on L1? It seems to be highly non-linear.

Suggest you plot at least the inductor current to get a better idea of what is happening.

@Andyaka The edit did not invalidate your answer. The circuit with the error is still in the question, and your answer explains why it doesn't behave properly, and there are significant spikes in the waveforms in both the correct and incorrect circuit.

@winny I am aware that an intermediate revision removed it, but the initial edit and the final edit contain it. I could have been more clear, but in any case the circuit with the error is in the version that matters: the current one.

@Null I see. Nuanced issue.

I think there are a couple of big reasons why you are not able to predict the voltages present in your simulation:

Maximum current through the inductor and MOSFET is ambiguous, since \$R_{DS}\$ is not well defined.

MOSFET switching time is too significant compared to the period of your switching signal. The transition between on and off isn't fast enough to produce the ideal instantaneous change of current paths from MOSFET to Rload.


I'll try to demonstrate and explain these points. When the MOSFET switches on, current through the inductor begins to rise, initially at a rate of:
$$ \frac{dI}{dt} = \frac{V_{CC}}{L_1} $$
The rate of rise of current diminishes over time to some maximum determined by the inductor's resistance and the MOSFET's channel resistance. MOSFET channel resistance is heavily dependent on \$V_{GS}\$, controlled by V2, and can only be approximated, or determined experimentally. It isn't even constant, varying somewhat with drain potential, so any expression you derive for drain current will necessarily be either approximate, or complicated.
The best approach to control maximum inductor/drain current is to endow the inductor with resistance (all inductors have some resistance), or equivalently to insert a known resistance in series with an ideal inductor. Then we can model the MOSFET as a plain switch:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
As long as this resistance \$R_1\$ is large compared to the transistor's channel resistance \$R_{DS}\$, then \$R_{DS}\$ can be neglected. After switch SW1 is closed, eventually node D potential will rise to \$V_D=+9V\$, and drain current will reach a maximum of:
$$ I_{D(MAX)} = \frac{V_D}{R_1} = \frac{9V}{10\Omega} = 900mA $$
In this condition, R2 is also passing current \$I_2\$:
$$ I_2 = \frac{V_D}{R_2} = \frac{+9V}{50\Omega} = 180mA $$
By KCL, inductor current is the sum of those two contributions:
$$ I_1 = I_D + I_2 = 1.08A $$
Now that \$I_1\$ is known, we can predict what happens immediately after SW1 is opened. The inductor will initially maintain \$I_1=1.08A\$, briefly becoming a current source, but there is now only one path for that current to flow, which is via R2:

simulate this circuit
Ohm's law tells us that the voltage across R2, which is also the potential \$V_D\$, will be:
$$ V_D = I_2 \times R_2 = 1.08A \times 50\Omega = 54V $$
This of course will diminish over time as the inductor's magnetic field collapses, and current falls.
With SW1 open or closed, the quiescent voltage \$V_{D(Q)} = +9V\$, so this will be the potential that node D returns to in the long term, following a change of switch state. These figures assume that we permit enough time between switch state changing, for \$I_1\$ and \$V_D\$ to settle. If switching frequency is too high, then we can expect smaller voltage transitions, as maximum current will be somewhat truncated.
We expect, then, under ideal circumstances, that \$V_D\$ should rise to +54V and fall to 0V, settling at +9V in between transitions of \$V_{IN}\$:

simulate this circuit

This treatment of the MOSFET as a switch is optimistic. Miller effects will cause transitions of gate potential to also appear (attenuated) at the drain, which will slow the switching on or off of that device. Also, don't forget that \$R_{DS}\$ is not zero.
Consequently, the transistor will not transition between fully on and fully off (as the above ideal switch scenario did), and the shift of current from transistor over to R2 will not be instantaneous. We will not observe the full 54V across R2, since the transistor's \$R_{DS}\$ does not rise instantly to infinity:

simulate this circuit

The simplest way to obtain behaviour closer to predicted, when using a real MOSFET, is to reduce the switching frequency, and increase L1 accordingly. This will ensure that the MOSFET switching time is very small compared to the time constant formed by R1, R2 and L1, so that switching is complete long before L1 current has changed significantly:

simulate this circuit

As for your concerns about there being negative voltage spikes, I don't see how that can be the case, in your circuit or mine. As far as I see, there can only be a positive potential spike at D.

Assuming an ideal switch, we can analyze this with a two-phase solution.

Assume initial conditions from the previous cycle (periodic steady state).
While the switch is on, Vcc is dropped across the inductor and current is rising.
While the switch is off, L1 decays exponentially into Rload.
If a high enough peak voltage is reached during (3), M1 will also avalanche, which we can model as a Thevenin equivalent load until voltage drops below avalanche threshold.

Thus we have a piecewise continuous sequence of events, element voltage/current is well defined, and while we may have a free variable (leftover current from decay), we can loop that in and solve it.
We start with supply V, inductor L, load R, ideal switch, frequency F, duty cycle D.
In the first phase, we have inductor voltage V.  The inductor equation is:
$$ V = L \frac{dI}{dt} $$
As V and L are constant during this phase, we can change dees to deltas.  The on-time is \$\Delta t = \frac{D}{F}\$.  The current at the end of this phase is simply,
$$ I_\text{initial} + \Delta I = I_\text{initial} + \frac{V D}{L F}$$
In the second phase, current discharges exponentially according to
$$ i(t) = \left( I_\text{initial} + \frac{V D}{L F} \right) e^{\frac{-t R}{L}} $$
t is time elapsed during the phase, so we substitute in the remaining time, \$t \rightarrow \frac{1-D}{F}\$.  Thus we have,
$$ I_\text{final} = \left( I_\text{initial} + \frac{V D}{L F} \right) e^{\frac{-(1-D) R}{LF}} $$
Voltage peak, assuming instantaneous switching and no capacitance, occurs just after switching, \$ \left( I_\text{initial} + \frac{V D}{L F} \right) R\$.
Again, if peak voltage exceeds avalanche, the voltage will be clamped until current decays out of that region; the above equations suffice to model this, and I will leave integrating this effect as an exercise to the reader.
Continuity condition: note that \$I_\text{initial} = I_\text{final}\$.  So we have,
$$ I_\text{final} \left(1 - e^{\frac{-(1-D) R}{LF}} \right) = \frac{V D}{L F} e^{\frac{-(1-D) R}{LF}} $$
$$ I_\text{final} = \frac{ \frac{V D}{L F} e^{\frac{-(1-D) R}{LF}} }{ 1 - e^{\frac{-(1-D) R}{LF}} } = \frac{V D}{L F} \frac{1}{ e^{\frac{(1-D) R}{LF}} - 1 } $$
Some checking is in order (also because I'm lazyas an exercise for the reader), but there's no weird instability, a single closed-form solution is obtained.  In dynamic terms, it's a simple 1st-order lossy system, so we expect a unique stable solution.
For the special case D = 0.5, we have
$$ I_\text{final} = \frac{V}{2 L F} \frac{1}{ e^{\frac{R}{2LF}} - 1 } $$
with two important factors, the overall magnitude \$\frac{V}{2 L F}\$, corresponding to the switch-on (charging) phase, and \$\frac{R}{2LF}\$, the time constant during the switch-off (discharge) phase.  If R/L is large, current largely discharges between pulses, and peak current (and voltage) is determined by the first factor.  If R/L is small, current builds up between cycles -- though if R is small, peak voltage won't be very large, either.
Note that we have LF in both terms.  Inductance is something of a conversion factor between driven frequency and circuit behavior.  Indeed, inductance has units of ohm-seconds, or ohms per Hz.  (What exactly those ohms mean, depends on the circuit, but it will be a ratio of some voltage and current somewhere.)
For constant V and R, if we increase L or F, we expect current to decrease: there's simply less charging time, even if the L/R time constant gets longer in the process (more current is stored from previous cycles).  We can prove this by approximating the exponential as its Taylor series,
$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
For small \$x\$ (L/R → ∞), \$e^x \approx 1 + x\$ and we have,
$$ I_\text{final} = \frac{V}{2 L F} \frac{1}{ 1 + \frac{R}{2LF} - 1 } = \frac{V}{2 L F} \frac{2LF}{R} = \frac{V}{R} $$
In other words, the switch effectively disappears and we have the DC case. (The power dissipated by the resistor, however, is still affected by the AC component: it sees double voltage half of the time, or double the power overall.)
If we reduce L or F, current generally increases, but we keep less of it from cycle to cycle: the exponential term dominates.  We get,
$$ V_\text{peak} \approx \frac{V D R}{L F}$$
Note that charging an inductor to arbitrarily high currents, puts the same current through the switch and supply. Real devices have resistance, and the charging phase is no longer a linear ramp, but a competing exponential.
Finally, a note (but not analysis) about including capacitance: at the instant of turn-off, the circuit becomes a parallel RLC network, with initial current in the inductor; ringdown ensues.  Depending on RLC values, this may peak and settle down (similar to the R-dominant case), or it may oscillate (in which case the MOSFET's body diode becomes relevant, clamping the negative ringdown phase(s) to ~ -1V).  There will be a finite \$\frac{dV}{dt}\$ on the rising edge, as the capacitor equation \$I = C\frac{dV}{dt}\$ applies.  The system has a 2nd order dynamic solution, which can be represented in terms of trig and exponential functions, or the complex exponential directly.

You must be more careful when making schematics: -

... Or you will get confusing results.
Your 2nd diagram is correct. The inductor will produce a flyback voltage when the MOSFET turns off. So, if you saw a peak of 85 volts, the current in the 50 Ω resistor must have been 1.7 amps for a short period of time.
I'm sure if you also plotted inductor current that would be seen to be the case.

Thank you for catching the error in the first schematic.  But I don't believe it answers the question: "For some L values, the spikes are positive; for others negative; and the magnitude varies greatly, increasing up to a certain point, then going to 0. How can I predict the voltage spikes?"  Can you shed some light on that?

Nice catch re lack of connection. I wonder what causes the negative spikes in the original circuit? The lack of an inductor should produce an all-positive result. Mayhaps the MOSFET model has some inductance other than between DS which interacts in a strange way. But, if so the inductance should be far far smaller than the external L and the 50 Ohm should clamp it rather better, I'd have thought.

@RussellMcMahon now that's a good question that only the OP can answer.
